# How does one express "to share" in Esperanto?

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context

There seems to be several words in Esperanto that all correspond to the English verb "to share". Right now I can think of dividi, diskonigi and kunhavi. I'd love to see a collection of them all, and in which situations to use which ones.

Comment: What about in the context of "sharing experience" or "sharing a story"?

Answer (score 41):

[image]

- dividi - to divide something into smaller pieces.
- kundividi - to share those pieces with other people. (everyone gets a bit)
- havigi - to make other people have something. In other words, to give, make available, provide, etc.
- kunhavigi - To make something common property of you and other people, without dividing it into pieces.

Notes:

- *dividi* is often used for *kundividi*

(Please comment for imprecisions or errors)

Comment: Awesome paint skills! ;) Although not very user-friendly for colorblind people. Could each stick-man have a label A/B/C somewhere close to its hear or body?

Comment: @LazarLjubenović Hopefully someone with good drawing skills will do it. (Which I don't have)

Comment: @LazarLjubenović Going by colorblind simulations using [Color Oracle](http://colororacle.org/), it's actually not bad as is. Mostly because the green person on the left is a noticably darker color than the red one on the right. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/kQziM7Q.png) is a simulation for the most common type of color blindness. For the next two most common types the difference is in fact even better to see.

Comment: @Vanege - Maybe add a short description in words along with the picture to make it clear for people who don't fully understand what it means. For example: **dividi** - to divide something into smaller pieces. **kundividi** - to share those pieces with other people. (everyone gets a bit) **havigi** - to make other people have something. In other words, to give, make available, provide, etc. **kunhavigi** - To make something common property of you and other people, without dividing it into pieces.

Comment: Oh, and "dishavigi" is actually to distribute something to a large amount of people. "dis-" means more or less "in many/all directions" (disdoni, diskonigi, disflui, etc.) or "into lots of small pieces" (disfali, disperdi, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

This question was discussed in the Facebook group Duolingo Esperanto Learners.

https://www.facebook.com/groups/duolingo.esperanto.learners/permalink/550406195121402/

There was some disagreement among the fluent speakers about how far the word *dividi* could be pushed without being considered an anglicism.

There are certainly many examples of *dividi* being used with thoughts, experience, expertise, and objects that are not chopped up and parted out. Based on examples found in the Tekstaro, *dividi* can be used with fate, thoughts, remarks, danger, happiness, and opinions

As for "sharing" things on Facebook, the term *diskonigi* is in use - possibly due to Richard Delemore's use of the term in his Evildea videos. Note that different social media use different expressions for this action. Certainly *dividi* and *reafiŝi* could also work.

Comment: What about just "afiŝi"? With the "re-" I expect a repeated action.

Comment: Repeated one time. Someone posts. You post it a second time. That's what "re" means.

Comment: Yes. "share" can be both "share my own thoughts" (afiŝi) and share someone else's post (reafiŝi). English is so imprecise. :-P

Comment: tweet and retweet. Afisxi kaj reafisxi.

Answer (score 1):

The anglicism "divide" for "sharing" is already present in many languages in which "share" and "divide" have the same meaning.

Let's check the original sources:

- komun' commun | common | gemeinsam | общій | ogólny, wspólny.
- divid' diviser, partager | divide | theilen | дѣлить | dzielić.
- part' partie, part | part | Theil | часть | część.
- kon' connaître | know (by experience or study), recognise | kennen | знать (быть знакомымъ) | znać.
- kun avec | with, (kune) together | mit | съ | z
- ig' make something like, apply attribute to something
- dis' make something separated

So:

- komunig' => make common
- partig' => make partitioned
- konig' => make known
- havig' => make having
- kundivid' => divide/split together
- disdivid' => divide/split into pieces
- diskonig' => make known into pieces
- kunhavig' => make having together (share ownership)
- kunkonig' => make known together (share knowledge)

Is kunhavig' actually a good word for sharing in social? "Hav'" suggests ownership but by "sharing" things on the internet the ownership does not change.

Kunkonig' looks better and more exact solution (make-known-together). Google Translate has it and translates exactly to what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Popartigi. (Sharing : giving each one his share).  Dispartigi. (Sharing : distribution) kunpartigi (sharing in common).  Partajxo. (A share).  Partajxi. (Sharing in general).  Popartajxo. (Contribution).

Answer (score 0):

Common for those forms of sharing that Vanege illustrated is that something is concretely or figuratively divided or split into parts.

In contrast if you share information, it is not split but rather the same information becomes available to others. For this kind of sharing there is a lot of variation. Some use *havigi*, but like the verb *prunti*, is not clear whether *havigi* results in that you have something ("make someone to act that you have") or the others ("make others to have"). Others use *komunigi*, but PIV has an example *komunigi la kampojn de vilaĝo* which leads one to think about somekind of co-owning.

Among the "best" is *diskonigi* as introduced by Evildea like Tomaso Alexander said. I personally prefer *partodoni* which the translation team of Joomla has chosen according to Stella Lindblom, the head of the Esperanto translation team of Joomla.