# Tradukoj por 'Post a post'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Tradukante Joomla Esperanten antaŭ kelkaj jaroj, troviĝis pluraj eblecoj, sed ekde tiam Komputeko ŝajne decidis ke 'post' (en) estas "afiŝo". Tio ne estas tute korekte laŭ PIV kiu donas aliajn sugestojn. Unu el ili ni uzas en Joomla; "notico".

En la angla troviĝas sinonimoj al "post", interalie 'message'. 'Post a post' aŭ 'Send a message' is pli-malpli la sama afero.

Lastatempe mi vidis "Afiŝi afiŝon", kio lamas se vi demandas min. "Afiŝo" estas 'granda papera mesaĝo al publiko'. "Notico" estas 'longa kaj detala priskribo pri iu temo', sekve ni tradukis al 'Sendi noticon'.

Ĉu vi havas aliajn ideojn?

---

Translating Joomla into Esperanto a few years back, there were several possibilities, but since then Komputeko has obviously made the decision that a post is an "afiŝo". That is not entirely correct according to PIV, which have other suggestions. One of which we use in Joomla; "notico".

In English there are synonyms to "post", like 'message'. 'Post a post' or 'Send a message' is more or less the same thing.

In recent days, I've come across "Afiŝi afiŝon", which is quite lame if you ask me. "Afiŝo" is 'a big poster put up on walls to officially inform people of some thing or activity'. A "notico" is 'a detailed text about a certain subject'. Thus we chose 'Sendi noticon'.

What is your take on this?

Comment: This question asks for opinions which makes it not suitable for stackexchange. The question could be rephrased into asking for *the* translation of 'post' or 'post a post' (preferably in a specific context), where 'sendi noticon' and 'afiŝi afiŝon' could be mentioned as two considerations that the question-asker for some (preferably specified) reason is unsure about.

Comment: Well, that's your opinion, man... There is no ONE answer here. I would like to know ALL proposals for an answer. Is that beyond the scope of SE?

Comment: On stackexchange, it has to be possible to answer a question fully with just *one* answer. If you want to know all possible translations of 'post' you can ask for a list of all possible translations and then any answers will try to make a complete list. See [this question](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/449/how-does-one-express-to-share-in-esperanto) for a good example of that.

Comment: Mi pensas ke marki gxin per flago estis nenecesa. Multaj demandoj cxi tie estas vortigitaj tiel, kaj efektive cxiu respondo estas iel prezento de siaj ”ideoj”.

Comment: That's soo... engineery. I'm apparently not geeky and left brained enough to fit into this place. Bye.

Answer (score 1):

Se un afiŝo estas tro granda, vi povas uzi la vorton *afiŝeto*. Mi ankaǔ trovas la vorton *bultenejo* "bulletin board" sed mi ne pensas ke *bulteno* estas trafa vorto por "post".

Answer (score 1):

- `afiŝo` precipe estas io kio estas metate ien publike - por preni. Iomete kiel "bulletin board" ktp.
- `mesaĝo` ankaŭ estas io komunikata, tamen jam kun intencita legant(ar)o.
- `notico` estas preskaŭ `noto` (vd `notlibro`) kaj mi asocias ĝin kun la germana `Notiz` kiu signifas io kia estas notoj dum iu prelego en la universitato aŭ alia protokolaĵo.

Now to the English usage: verbal usage as in `posting` would not favor `notico`, demarcation of similar terms `blog` (`blogo`, `protokolo`) seems fine for all.
The English definition of "posting" - a *notice* /display in a public place

Somehow `afiŝo` I do not find that bad, conveying a posting to the public. `mesaĝo` (~ something posted) would always do.
`notico` I find okay, but as independant stem a bit redundant, and missing the richness of `noto/noti/notlibro`. And missing the "public" annotation of say `bulteno`. Maybe less suited.