# How to express "to share a hotel room" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, meaning-in-context

To save money, two or more people might book and use a single two- or multi-bed hotel room together, rather than each a hotel room for themselves, i.e., they share a hotel room.

How would this be expressed in Esperanto? Can **"kunhavigi"** as per [Vanege's answer](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/450/1576) to [How does one express "to share" in Esperanto?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/449/1576) be used, even though the guest won't *own* the hotel room? Would **"kunuzi"** be better in that regard? Or is there some completely other way to convey this scenario concisely?

---

Por ŝpari monon, du aŭ pli homoj povus mendi kaj uzi (t.e., tie tranokti) du- aŭ plur-litan hotelĉambron kune, anŝtataŭ ĉiu po apartan hotelĉambron.

Kiel oni esprimu tion en Esperanto? Ĉu per **"kunhavigi"** laŭ [la respondo de Vanege](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/450/1576) al [How does one express "to share" in Esperanto?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/449/1576), kvankam la ĉambron ne apartenus al ili (t.e., ili nur lu-posedus kaj ne proprietus la ĉambron)? Ĉu **"kunuzi"** estus pli taŭga? Aŭ ĉu estas tute alia maniero esprimi tian situacion koncize?

Answer (score 2):

Vi povas ĝenerale uzi `dividi`, ĉi okaze, la ĉambron. Oni vidas la ĉambro kiel tuton, kaj ĉiu ricevas/prenas sian "parton" (liton, angulon, breton...). *Ĉambro*, en via situacio, estas iel metaa, do oni povas subkompreni *prezon*.

```
Ni dividu ĉambron
```

`dividi` ([PIV](https://vortaro.net/#dividi_kdc)):

```
b) kiam ĉiu prenas sian havotaĵon:
dividi heredon kun fratoj
```

Se la kunteksto estas evidenta por ĉiuj, dum vi organizas tian vojaĝon, la jeno kompreneblus:

```
Ni dormu/loĝu samĉambre
Ni luprenu/mendu plurlitajn ĉambrojn
```

La demando menciita de vi pravigus tiun uzon de `dividi` eĉ se vi opinias ke `kundividi` estus pli ĝusta.

Oni uzas tiun frazon ankaŭ en la [mendilo](https://uea.org/pdf/uk2022/Mendilo_Montrealo_2022.pdf) por la Universala Kongreso en Montrealo 2022 (kio estas indico de kompreneblo):

[image: Mi dividos la ĉambron kun kongresano(j)]

> Mi dividos la ĉambron kun kongresano(j) _________
> _________, kies kongresa(j) numero(j) estas _________
> […]

Answer (score 2):

*JES okazis en hotelo Botax ... ĉiuj, kiuj mendis propran ĉambron povis havi propran, sen bezoni **kunloĝi kun** hazardaj **aliuloj***. https://sezonoj.ru/2016/01/hungario/

Answer (score 1):

More generally about sharing…

#### dividi

"to divide"

1. in sense of mathematics: *dividi 20 per 3*

2. to divide into parts:.

- *La rivero dividas la urbon en du partojn.*

Note, that the parts need not to be equal-sized, but often are presumed to be:

- *dividi kukon en kvar partojn*

If you need to specify that the parts are equal-sized, use *egale dividi, duonigi, trionigi…*

#### distribui

"to distribute"

- *distribui monon al la malriĉuloj*

Once again the parts need not to be equal-sized, but often are presumed to be.

#### disdividi

"to spread out, to split"

- *disdividi substancon en medion*
- *disdividi la landon inter si*

Presumed to be an unequal division.

#### onigi

"to divide into parts"

= *dividi (en la matematika senco)*

Naturally there are the more specific *duonigi, trionigi…*

#### partigi

"to divide into parts"

- *partigi la laboron*

= *dividi (en la ne-matematika senco)*

This is often understood to mean an unequal division.

## conclusion

Common for all those above is that something is concretely or figuratively divided or split into parts. In your example of sharing a hotel room, it is like Eduardo Trápani says, you are most likely referring to sharing the price. For that *dividi* is fine. *Kunuzi* will also do, but that refers to sharing the room itself, and says nothing about sharing the price.

Answer (score 1):

Ni kunluis (kunrezervis, kunprenis...) hotelĉambron.  Mi kunluis (kunrezervis, kunprenis...) hotelĉambron kun mia kunvojaĝanto.

Ni prenis ĉambron po du.  Mi prenis ĉambron po du kun mia kunvojaĝanto.